# String trim from back to specific three characters

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, reverse

How can I trim some string until I got three specific characters which are the same as, for example, "xyz". To be precise I will give an example:

```
Dim String1 as String = "GunsAndRosesWelcomeToTheJungle" 
Dim String2 as String = "DontCry"
Dim ResultString as String
```

I need to remove everything from right until I get `"moc" (reverse "com")` in `String1` and add `string2` to get `ResultString`.

The ResultString should be: `"GunsAndRosesWelDontCry"`

Comment: What about [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO) ?

Comment: wingedpanther, as I said, problem is when i have some more "com" characters. Ian and jhamon gave me an answer. Simple using String.LastIndexOf

Comment: I've used `GunsAndRosesWelcomeTocomeThecomJunglecom`(_4 nos. of  com_) in my example

Comment: Ohh..sorry.. i haven't seen that well :) Well done, man!

Comment: Sure you can. It is an answer, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String.IndexOf` and the `String.Substring` and start from in front to solve it:

```
Dim String1 as String = "GunsAndRosesWelcomeToTheJungle" 
Dim String2 as String = "DontCry"
Dim index = String1.IndexOf("com")
Dim ResultString as String = String1.Substring(0, index) + String2
```

Edit:

If both the substring input and the string need to be reversed for one reason or another, I would introduce a reverse string function like this

```
Private Function Reverse(Val As String) As String
    Dim charArray As Char() = Val.ToCharArray()
    Array.Reverse(charArray)
    Return New String(charArray)
End Function
```

And then use it like this

```
Dim String1 As String = "GunsAndRosesWelcomeToTheJungle"
Dim String2 As String = "DontCry"        
Dim index = String1.Length - Reverse(String1).IndexOf(Reverse("com")) - ("com").Length
Dim ResultString As String = String1.Substring(0, index) + String2
```

Else, we can use `String.LastIndexOf`

```
Dim String1 as String = "GunsAndRosesWelcomeToTheJungle" 
Dim String2 as String = "DontCry"
Dim index = String1.LastIndexOf("com")
Dim ResultString as String = String1.Substring(0, index) + String2
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, but I need to do that from backward. What if I have situation that I have two or three places where is "com" and I need the last one?

Comment: @user5804260 I see, it has to be read from backwards by requirement, is it?

Comment: simply use `LastIndexOf`

Comment: Ian, jhamon - thank you. With String.LastIndexOf works fine for me.

Comment: I already did it, but I'm new here, so, it will be visible soon :)

Comment: @user5804260 oh, great! Glad that the answer can be useful! =D and again, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
Dim String1 As String = "GunsAndRosesWelcomeTocomeThecomJunglecom"
Dim String2 As String = "DontCry"
Dim ResultString As String
Dim ar As String() = String1.Split("com")
ResultString = ar(0) & String2
```

---

[`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO)